# Angular $http empty error object on failed requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm  posting successfully to my server , however when requests fails the error object is empty and i cannot construct logic based on the error code
Here is the code and what i see on DEV tools

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'my remote api/',
        data: {'Account' : $scope.userPhoneNumber, 'Initiator' : initiator.toString()},
        headers: {"Authorization": "Basic register:register"}
    }).
    then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.AuthenticationUid);
        openModalWindow(initiator, response.data.AuthenticationUid);
    }, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.phoneNotFound = true;
    });
```

[image]

As you can see the printed data object shows status as -1 while it should show 404....

Answer (score 0):

The console output indicates that you are not successfully POSTing to the server. Your OPTIONS request is successful, but your post fails due to missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers which is indicative of a CORs error.

Without knowledge of your server it's a bit hard to give you an exact solution, but searching for something along the lines of 'setting up CORS in ' should get you on the right track.

Comment: I dont know why its showing CORS error but ignore this there isnt any CORS issue ,the error code is 404 not found, if i submit data that is present on the server i get 200 and the data, There isnt any CORS issue.

Comment: The error code being -1 isn't an issue on the angular side. Can you update your question to show the server code?

Comment: Im a consumer of the API ,i have no access to its code. However browser does detect the correct error code being 404 so i dont think its a server issue

Comment: Have a look at the response tab for the network request to see what data is being sent back from the server. I'm assuming that the object you are logging is from your console.log(data) statement?

Comment: The response tab says "This request has no response data available" ,and yes ,im logging the data variable passed as inside the function that is the second param to the 'then' function

Comment: Have you set up any interceptors?

Comment: No interceptors, no other config to $http

Comment: Ok then I think this comes back to the idea of it being a CORs issue. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2798 Talks about how CORs can affect the status value of the response object and the fact that you don't have any interceptors leads me to believe that it is a server side issue.

Comment: I checked the link you provided, the last remark there looks exactly like my isse, I asked the API team to add the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" so see if this fix the issue mentioned in github, ill update